# Powershell: put yesterday's date in a filename

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to do the following three steps with a powershell script:

1. drop the file extension (.part) of all files ending with the pattern "*flv.part". So files ending with ".flv.part" would now end simply with ".flv".
2. Add yesterday's date (in YYYYMMDD format) at the beginning of the filename of these FLV files.
3. Move these flv files to some other directory.

I figured out the first and the last step. But I can't figure out the middle step (the second step where I add yesterday's date to the beginning of the filename).

Here's what I have figured out:

```
cd C:\Users\appa\Desktop
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace ".part","" }
---------this step needs to add yesterday's date (in YYYYMMDD format) to filename--------
move-item -path .\*.flv -destination d:\D:\VideoCaptures
```

Any ideas anyone? I'm using windows 7 with powershell v2.

EDIT: Thanks everyone for your contributions! I have made the following script for this task:

```
cd C:\Users\appa\Desktop
$dt_str = (get-date).AddDays(-1).tostring("yyyyMMdd")
Dir *.part | Rename-Item -NewName { $dt_str + "-" + $_.name -replace ".part","" }
move-item -path .\*.flv -destination D:\VideoCapture
```

EDIT: This is purely for FYI purposes...I've already up-voted the helpful posts and marked a post as an answer, but SU says that it won't reflect my votes until I reach 10 or something reputation. So please wait till that time for my votes to become "visible"! :)

Comment: `[DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')`

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks for the command! But how do I use it to at the beginning of the filename while renaming it? I mean I want to preserve the rest of the filename of the FLVs while adding this (yesterday's) date at the beginning? How should I structure the -replace command for that? It was easier to cut-off the ".part" extension but i can't figure out adding this at the beginning..

Comment: @beck2haml - Are you actually replacing part of the file name with yesterday's date or are you simply prepending?

Comment: @beck2haml Why do you need `-replace`? Did not good old plus work for you (`(something) + $_.name`)? And, BTW, you can use `-replace '^',(something)`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Oh yeah! I totally forgot about the plus operator!!

Comment: @Enigmativity yeah..i should have framed the question better. I am actually prepending yesterday's date to the filenames of those FLVs.

Comment: @beck2haml Please mark one of the answers as accepted.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov I already did! But SU says that my vote would be reflected only when my reputation is beyond 10 or something...!!! So please wait for some time..!!

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. [See Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$date = Get-Date
$date = $date.AddDays(-1)
$dateStr = $date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName {  $dateStr  + $_.name -replace ".flv.part",".flv"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read about [Get-Date](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730960.aspx) method and [Formatting Dates](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx) , please.

*For example for current date:*

`$dt = Get-Date -format 'yyyyMMdd'`

*or for yesterday*

`$dt = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')`

Other functions you can use:

- [Get-Item cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849788.aspx), *for example:* `Get-Item -Path "C:\Windows\*.flv.part"`
- [Path Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx), *for example:* `[System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension(".flv.part", ".flv")`
- [Move-Item cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176910.aspx),

Maybe something like this:

```
$dt = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')

Get-Item -Path "C:\Windows\*.flv.part" | Foreach-Object -Process { 

    $newpath = Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath "$dt-$($_.BaseName).flv" # in PowerShell "" it's a Magic String

    Move-Item -Path $newpath -Destination "??"
}
```

Please be aware about [PowerShell’s Type Conversion Magic](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2013/06/11/understanding-powershells-type-conversion-magic/) in PowerShell ;)